# Load PDF through colorbox

Tags: javascript

I am trying to load a PDF from a link using [colorbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox) but although the colorbox window opens the pdf is just text characters. This is what the link looks like:

This is what my link looks like:

```
<a href="http://example.com/sites/default/files/menus/menu.pdf?width=500&height=500&iframe=false" class="colorbox colorbox-load">View</a>
```

and when it's rendered out it looks like this:

```
<a href="http://example.com/sites/default/files/menus/menu.pdf?width=500&amp;height=500&amp;iframe=true" class="colorbox colorbox-load init-colorbox-processed cboxElement">View</a>
```

which looks right to me but the pdf is just text characters. The pdf loads fine just as a link opened in your browser.

Comment: Where are you making the link at?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you, use this module https://www.drupal.org/project/pdf_to_imagefield since colorbox is designed to display images.

If you still want to show the complete pdf. You could embed it in a basic page:

Download file

You can then reference the page by node id.

Link name